# SVG defs not loaded in <use> tag

Tags: html, css, svg

I load an SVG symbol in my webpage using `<use xlink:href="reddit.svg#logo">`. While this loads the symbol element itself, it doesn't load the relevant `<defs>` section. This results in a broken image.

I've tried moving `<defs>` inside `<symbol>`, that doesn't work either. What am I missing?

I have a full repro at https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-gagarin-u6jrn?file=/index.html . I've included the code below for convenience:

index.html

```
<svg className="classone">
   <use xlink:href="reddit.svg#logo"></use>
</svg>
```

reddit.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="256px" height="256px" viewBox="0 0 256 256" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
    <defs>
        <mask id="Mask">
            ...
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <symbol id="logo" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
        <circle fill="red" cx="128" cy="128" r="128" mask="url(#Mask)"></circle>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, old Chrome bug I believe (works fine in Firefox).

Comment: Ugly workaround: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-frost-4l20n?file=/index.html